# What am I doing wrong with this ant build file to create a web service client?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I'm trying to use an ant build script to create a web  service client  as given [here](http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/web-service/1145-how-create-java-web-service.html)

Here's my ant build file :`wsbuild.xml`

```
<project name="My Web Service Build" default="wsimport">

    <target name="wsimport">

        <exec executable="wsimport">

            <arg line="-keep -s ./src -p com.test http://localhost:1234/HelloWeb?wsdl"/>

        </exec>           

    </target>



</project>
```

And here is the project structure .

[image: Project Structure]

I get the following error.

```
  BUILD FAILED
    C:\Users\User\workspace_ee\WebService\com\wsbuild.xml:5: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "wsimport": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Any idea as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Ant cannot locate the `src` folder relative to the `wsbuild.xml`. Move the build file to the project folder - i.e. `C:\Users\User\workspace_ee\WebService`

Comment: I tried that and added `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin` to both the `PATH` and `Classpath` variables .  The error persists

Comment: `wsbuild.xml` needs to be in the project folder not the `com` directory so that it can access the `src` folder. Move the file to that folder

Comment: I think Im doing that here http://postimg.org/image/55kwzjr4t/. It still throws the same error. Or am I  doing something wrong?

Comment: No the file is at the same level as the source files now. Drag the file onto `WebService` to move it

Comment: Worked when I tried it from the link page. Are you getting the same error msg?

Comment: Ensure that you're running Ant using a JDK rather than a JRE so that wsimport is found (can be done by right clicking project in Eclipse And Window > Run As... > Ant build... > JRE > Separate JRE)

Comment: I think Im using the JRE.  http://postimg.org/image/igysj5onj/ . Isnt it supposed to be this way?

Comment: No, there's your problem - select a JDK from the combo there

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use something like this:

The path where you can find wsimport(Usually in java_home\bin)